# Export sql server tables / Reimport the rows that do not exist using vb6

Tags: sql-server, database, import, vb6, export

I hope the title is Clear enough.... So you could Help me!
I Tried a lot but no result

I'm using vb6 , I have a SQL Server database (5 tables) and connected to it using ado .. and there is a lot of rows in each table .

until Now every thing is fine .. Now I have this code to Compare and insert Rows that exist in a table in a DataBase and does Not exist in the same table in other DataBase

Example Code:

```
INSERT INTO Con1.TABLENAME2 (col1, Col2, col3) SELECT * FROM Con2.tablename1 A WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT *
          FROM Con1.tablename2 B
          WHERE A.col1 = B.col1
     )
```

Now the Problem is How can I Export my sql server database to a file using a vb6 code , so I put it in a usb and then Import it into other PC using the Program again .. and the program should Compare the two databases and insert the rows that not exist in the database that he is connected to ...

...
For security issues I should Not use network in this operation ...
**Like this :**

**BtnExport** : Export (He should make a File (.bak or anything) From The database (DB1) and I will put that File in a usb ... and put it in other PC .. the Program is installed in that Computer also and connected to another Database (DB2) but the same Tables (not the same Rows))

**BtnImport** : Import (I wil select that .bak File and the Program should Compare the Tables and insert in (DB2) the rows that exits in (DB1) and Not exist in (DB2) as the Example code said ...

Hope you Understand What I want to do ....
Thank U in advance ! :)

Comment: You need to add some more detail here before you'll get decent answers.  From your query, why wouldn't you do this all in SQL?  Is the query just an example of the behavior you want, or does the insert actually succeed?  Why go offline at all if it's not necessary?

Comment: edited ... i hope u could Help me
and what do u mean by 'do this all in SQL' ?

Comment: If you want to do this in VB then use ADO to select the recordset from the source database, iterate the records and write the field values to a file. Then for the target database do the reverse. If you need some specific help you'll need to show your code and indicate where you are having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have linked servers (as would be indicated by your query) you can just execute SQL queries from the connected server to the linked server, without ever needing to store anything outside a sql table.  Setup and Use of linked servers varies with each type of server (and they may even be called something different, where I currently work we use Oracle and it's definitely not linked, but I can't find it in the docs right now) So in your above query as an Oracle example, I could:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME2@Con1 (col1, Col2, col3) SELECT * FROM tablename1@Con2 A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename2@Con1 B WHERE A.col1 = B.col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution Guys ...
First I should Configure my sql server Database By executing these Codes in a new query

```
sp_configure 'show advanced option', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
```

and

```
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
```

And then to export and import :

--Export

```
INSERT INTO OpenRowSet
('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',      -- Provider
'E:\DBs\DB.mdb';  -- Data Source
'admin'; -- User ID
'', -- Password
Table1)  
 Select * from Table1
```

--Import

```
INSERT INTO Table1 

 Select * from OpenRowSet
('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',      -- Provider
'E:\DBs\DB.mdb';  -- Data Source
'admin'; -- User ID
'', -- Password
Table1) A WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT *
          FROM Table1 B
          WHERE A.N = B.N
     )
```

Thanks For Ur Help Guys :) !